# m2eclipse will not download any dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies

I was hoping someone might be able to help.

On a brand new windows machine. I've downloaded and installed java jdk before downloading and running the latest version of eclipse (indigo).

From there I have installed the maven integration plugin from the marketplace and created a new maven projected.

The project has a ton of errors mainly to do with missing dependencies or life cycle management.

When I do maven-clean I get the following error message:

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.4.1 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Invalid argument: getsockname to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom -> [Help 1]
```

I am not behind a firewall and I do not use a proxy. My maven settings.xml is completely default as is my maven project. No classes added, nothing added to the pom.

Can anyone help?

All the best.

p.s here are the errors shown in the pom:

1:

```
CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.3.2: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.3.2 from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.3.2 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Invalid argument: getsockname to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.3.2/maven-compiler-plugin-2.3.2.pom
```

2:

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)
```

3:

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)
```

4:

```
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.4.3 from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.4.3 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Invalid argument: getsockname to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.4.3/maven-resources-plugin-2.4.3.pom
```

Comment: Have you turned of the firewall in Windows, cause windows turns on by default a firewall which could sometimes the problems.

Answer (score 1):

Furthermore i recommend to test the configuration etc. first with command line client of Maven (Maven 3.0.X) and not within Eclipse.

The 1./4. shows that you have tried to download some artifact which has failed for whatever reasons. The simple solution for that is to delete the local repository and retry the build. But i recommend to do that first on command line to check if everything is fine.

The 2./3. are indications that the project you are trying to compile does not contain a correct plugin coverage for [m2e which can be read in the docs](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered) how to solve that.

Comment: Hi khmarbaise, running mvn clean build from the command line worked like a charm. All of the dependencies were downloaded the the goals were successful. Any idea why it wouldn't work in eclipse?

Comment: Have you correctly configured the location of your settings.xml file in Eclipse this is often the root cause of such problems. The part 2./3. is only m2e related and will not cause any trouble in Maven itself.

Answer (score 0):

Problem:
  You are missing an artefact in Your maven repository.

How to verify:
  If You will browse Your repository You will find out that under .m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/ artefact will have lastUpdated suffix - maven attempted to download this artefact but failed.
 

How to solve:
  Just add an appropriate artefact into Your maven repository:) There are several ways how to do that but the simplest one will be dropping the folder with the missing artefact. Add since You can build Your project from the CMD just add missing artefact as a dependency into Your project. Build the project from the CMD.

Answer (score 0):

Add dependency is not working through eclipse IDE(JUNO 4.2). Fixed the issue by manually adding dependencies with the below command on command prompt

1. go to the location where your pom.xml is located
2. mvn install
3. once you see status BUILD success from now onwards we can proceed with IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly this is an issue of proxy. Either use VPN or edit procy setting in setting.xml. I searched lot about this error. Finally, I used VPN(Virtual private network ) to disable the proxy and was able to use cetral repository of Maven.

IF you dont want to USE VPN just change Settings.xml host address with proxy address  of ur company(which is available in  IE->tools->connection->LAN settings->advanced->http. )

Answer (score 0):

This is a proxy problem:

1. add your proxy config in your setting.xml
2. remove .m2 folder from your home directory
3. run any maven command in interactive mode from command line, for example try to create a project 
   mvn archetype: `generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp  -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app  -DartifactId=my-webapp`
4. that's all

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was because I configured the repository in the `settings.xml` of my Maven Installation. But this in not used by Eclipse as it comes with its own Maven implementation. You need to configure the repositories (mirror section) in the settings.xml in your profile (`.m2/settings.xml`).

Comment: Or make Eclipse use your own external Maven runtime. I prefer that myself because then you don't have differences in versions, but its an extra setup step every time you create a workspace of course.